# Only 2 sprites added on screen pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple pygame maze and I have a problem that only 2 sprites are displayed: a player and a single wall, while i see that they are all added to the sprite list correctly

```
PINK = (221, 160, 221)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (29, 32, 76)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 30


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, img='alien.png'):
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load(img).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        # Set speed vector
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.walls = None

    def update(self):

        # Horizontal movement
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        # Check if object stumbles upon an obstacle
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            if self.change_x > 0:  # If the object was moving right
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left  # Align its right border with the left border of an obstacle

            else:  # If the object was moving left
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right  # Align its left border with the right border of an obstacle

        # Vetical movement
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        # Check if object stumbles upon an obstacle
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            if self.change_y > 0:  # If the object was moving up
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top  # Align its upper border with the down border of an obstacle

            else:  # If the object was moving down
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom  # Align its down border with the up border of an obstacle


class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption('Maze game')

all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

for x in range(len(walls)):
    for y in range(len(walls)):
        if walls[x][y] == 1:
            #print(x, y)
            wall = Wall(x, y, 20, 20)
            wall_list.add(wall)
            all_sprite_list.add(wall)

player = Player(maze.start[0], maze.start[1])
player.walls = wall_list
all_sprite_list.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.change_x = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.change_x = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.change_y = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.change_y = 3

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.change_x = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.change_x = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.change_y = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.change_y = 0
    screen.fill(PINK)

    all_sprite_list.update()
    all_sprite_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

where `maze.grid` is a 2D np array made from 0's and 1's and `maze.start` is a tuple like (0, 9).
When I change height and width parameters in line `wall = Wall(x, y, 20, 20)` to `wall = Wall(x, y, 1, 1)` i see a tiny maze appearing on the screen, but if i increase the height and width of a wall i just see a single square at the top left corner of the window. I assume that the problem is that i want it to add each wall on 20x20px block but instead it adds on 1x1px block. How can I fix this?
Is there a way to treat coordinates not by just 1x1px block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, all objects are drawn, but drawn one on top of the other.

In the nested loop `x` and `y`  are the index in the grid (`walls`),  but not the coordinate of the upper left corner. You need to calculate the coordinate of the corner of each cell by multiplying it by the size of a cell (20):

<s>`wall = Wall(x, y, 20, 20)`</s>

```py
wall = Wall(x*20, y*20, 20, 20)
```